# Define address depending on target

Tags: ada, memory-address

I have a gpr project with 2 targets :

```
mySources  := "My project files"
case Rules.Target is
    when "CASE1" =>
         mySources := "File1" & mySources 
    when "CASE2" =>
         mySources := "File2"  & mySources 
    when others =>
end case
for Source_Dirs use mySources
```

I have `File1` containing the variable `local_Address` :

```
local_Address : constant System.Address := Function_to_get_Address();
```

On a `commonFile` I want to do :

```
-- Type definition
type My_Array_Type is array (Boolean) of My_Type;

-- Variable definition
My_Array : My_Array_Type;
for My_Array'Address use local_Address; --only for CASE1
```

How can I write my `file2` to have default address ? Or maybe I have to redefine my software design ?

**Edit**:

In `CASE2` I don't want to specify any address.

Comment: It is simple if you create two projects, one using File1 and one using File2. You may want to put File1 in a different file system directory than File2 so that the two files can be named the same, allowing the Ada context clauses for the rest of the program to be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use here is employing either `SEPARATE` or else alternate bodies. So, given the following spec/body, `Separate_Addresses.ads`/`Separate_Addresses.adb` —

```
Package Separate_Addresses with Pure is
   Function Get_Address return System.Address;
   Function Some_Common_Address return System.Address;
End Separate_Addresses;
---------------------------
Package Body Separate_Addresses is
   Function Get_Address return System.Address is Separate;
   Function Some_Common_Address return System.Address is
    ( ##COMMON_ADDRESS## );
End Separate_Addresses;
```

you would have another body file (`Separate_Addresses-Get_Address.adb`) like

```
Separate (Separate_Addresses)
Function Get_Address return System.Address is
Begin
   Return ##WHATEVER_ADDRESS##;
End;
```

for any of the unique & system-dependent addresses you need. Just store each separate-completion's body in a subfolder which is included in the "source directories" in the GPR based on the system. -- This has the advantage of (a) isolating the system-dependent parts, and (b) abstracting the system-dependencies to a common interface, **and** (c) collecting the dependencies into both the smallest units possible and the all the items for that particular system together.

The second method: write a system-specific body for each of the systems you're using, matching the common spec, and employ the `FOR Include Path USE ...` of the GPR, selecting the proper system-directory and appending that to the Include_Path; I forget the syntax but it's something like:

Sys : String;
case Operating_System_Flag is
when Win   => Sys:= "Windows";
when Mac   => Sys:= "Macintosh";
when Linux => Sys := "Linux";
end case;
For Include_Path("Ada") use ("src**", Sys);

**NOTE:** I've forgotten the exact syntax for GPR, but you have to do something like that. If you're using GNAT Programming Studio, I think you can right-click the project, select "View Source", in the tab of the window there should be a "Scenario" tab, click it, under the "Scenario Variables" click the "+" button, this will pull up a dialog where you can give a variable a name and possible values... this is where you set up the elements for the `CASE` above.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I made a mistake in my question (I edited it). I don't want to specify address in my second case, I want to do as default.

Comment: @A.Pissicat - Then what's the problem? You have two files, one with the addresses specified, the other without, and select the appropriate one  as you wish. For your "I want to do case_2 when I hit default" then just duplicate case_2's code.... or if you want to mitigate copy-errors, move the code to `others` and delete case_2 altogether, allowing the default to take care of it, too.

Comment: Solution of duplicate my `commonFile` works but it's a big file. I want to duplicate only the type definition. I'm new to Ada, and I only found how to separate a function/procedure.

Comment: You cannot use `separate` on variables and constants (or types), only subprograms and package-bodies. You *might* be able to use expression-statements with specifying the address: `Something : Some_Type with Address => (case OS is when Win => 123, when Mac => 321)`.  (WARNING: IIUC, this only works when the selection is purely static.)